# My chat tags are borderless

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, chat

When I post a tag into chat, borders on my tags are missing, but other's tags have them:

[image]

also:

[image]

inspecting the page source, the style attribute for my tags are missing:

*normal tag*

```
<span class="ob-post-tag" style="background-color: #E0EAF1; color: #3E6D8E; border-color: #3E6D8E; border-style: solid;">redacted</span>
```

*my tags*

```
<span class="ob-post-tag" style="">border</span>
```

This persists through a refresh, and others see the same thing.  Only my tags appear to be affected.

This seems to be a client issue.

- Persistent even after a browser restart.
- Persistent between *different browsers on the same computer*. ([wtf](/questions/tagged/wtf))
- Persistent between different users on the same computer.
- **Not** persistent however between computers (but on the same user).

Showing that this issue is specific to a computer:

[image]

Comment: Crazy voodoo stuff. Thought it was because your name was being shortened but no.

Comment: I wish my tags were as cool as yours.

Comment: This appears to have corrected it self.  Weird.

Comment: you're not alone any longer - ref http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8176959#8176959 (via [Shog9](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8177173#8177173))

Comment: Well, at least I know I wasn't imagining it.  I haven't experienced this issue since.

Comment: And here we go, two more: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9030609#9030609 http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9271129#9271129

Comment: The site logo also disapears on one-boxing.

Comment: Has anyone watching this post been able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  Old chat messages affected by this will not be repaired, but any new messages shouldn't be affected.  I never really found a way to reproduce it, so if it happens again just drop a comment here and I'll see what's up.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the root cause?

Comment: I figured out a fix without really getting to the root, but the proximate cause was that a styling string that should have been injected into the rendering was `null`.  The root cause would be whatever is causing that, but that's the part I couldn't reproduce.  It's intermittent and fairly rare.