# I'm cursed! Well.. kind of

Tags: bug, tags, chat

In the chat room I was writing messages asking to close vote something when I noticed my tag had become flat without a shadow like so:

[image: Normal tags]

Instead mine were flat!

[image: Flat tags]

But everyone else's was normal..

[image: Everyone is normal]

So my question is, why are my tags so weird compared to everyone else's? Is it a bug?

EDIT:

Mysticial has pointed out how it varies between two computers in the same user:

[image: Mysticial's stuff]

---

**The one-boxes are also affected:**

[image]

Comment: Don't worry, I'll be flat just for you. <3

Comment: FWIW, I copy and pasted the markdown for his messages, and I get a shadow like everyone else.

Comment: You are the chosen one.

Comment: I knew that if I asked this I would get the meta rep, but I was too lazy :P

Comment: Hmm... I have an idea. Try filling out the rest of your user profile.

Comment: I know of another user who was able to reproduce this.

Comment: It happened to me too!

Comment: I've tried my damnedest to make it happen to me, but I've failed. Although @Mysticial seems to have caught the virus.

Comment: Some of the chat rooms are now as amusing as the Teacher's Lounge.

Comment: I had this happen a while ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161243/my-chat-tags-are-borderless?noredirect=1#comment540775_161243

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Yeah! I just read it. I wonder what caused it.

Comment: no idea.  It resolved itself shortly after I posted that question, and hasn't happened since.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Rule one about borderless tag club is that you don't talk about borderless tag club, that's why.

Comment: :( borderless tag club should be renamed metro tag club.

Comment: I just saw this in c++ room: http://imgur.com/DTiHEjk

Comment: Upgrade your version of Mosaic!